# Sqoop job Unrecognized argument: --merge-key

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to create a Sqoop job with incremental lastmodified, but it throws  ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --merge-key. Sqoop job:

> sqoop job --create ImportConsentTransaction -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart:3306/production --table ConsentTransaction --fields-terminated-by '\b' --incremental lastmodified --merge-key transactionId --check-column updateTime --target-dir '/user/hadoop/ConsentTransaction' --last-value 0 --password-file /user/hadoop/sqoop.password --username user -m 1

Answer (score -1):

Add `--incremental lastmodified`.